# How to identify next span with css class name?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC code like this:

```
@Html.Label("Last Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required-label" }) <br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { maxlength = 20, @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "off" })
<span id="spnRCLastName" class="text-danger"></span>
```

I set Javascript validation based on some condition on keypress event. I use myform since we have multiple input elements

```
$('#myform input').keypress(function (e) {
    if ($(this).length > 0)
        $(this).closest(".text-danger).empty();
});
```

However `$(this).closest(".text-danger")` is not identifying the `<span>` element. I tried:

```
$(this).next("span")
$(this).nextAll("span:first")
```

but no luck. How to identify the immediate next span with class name?

Comment: Use `$(this).next(".text-danger").empty();`

Comment: `closest()` looks for the nearest parent matching the given selector, so wouldn't work. However `$(this).next('span')` should have worked fine. Check your console for errors. Also note that your length check in the event handler is redundant, as the element has to exist in order for the event to fire.

Comment: @DharaParmar pls see comment below, i tried with next and nextAll, but didn't work.

Comment: Your going about this the wrong way. Just clearing the text will not prevent validation and the message will display again when you submit (and if you were able to submit, then `ModelState` would be invalid on the controller. Use conditional validation attributes applied to you model properties, for example a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a parent div for the group:

```
<div>
    @Html.Label("Last Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required-label" }) <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { maxlength = 20, @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "off" })
    <span id="spnRCLastName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

In JS

```
$(this).parent().find("span").empty();
```